# Centering a lightbox - major is

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook, popup

ive made a tiny lightbox in jquery and css like facebooks image popup plugin, but i have this one issue where i cant get it to center.
To be honest, im not very good at css.

So here is the problem, its an updates page like where you see status updates from your pals and stuff.
As the user scrolls down, and clicks on an image. The lightbox keeps going down because of some property in the css. Ive been trying for about 2 days, cant figure it out.
I like how in facebook, where ever on the page you are, it appears right in the middle.
Id like to do this too.

If you dont understand what i mean, here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Dwt7k/4/

Try clicking on the image on the second post(if you dont see the image, you might see a silver rectangle sort of box above the orange lame/cool meter-thats the one)

And see how its downer..Thats the issue i have

Comment: You could not have made a mess complex example.

Comment: Im sorry, its just that im on dialup and i cant correct things it would take me hours..

Comment: Aha ok then, I'm working on a simple solution for you.

Comment: sounds like sarcasam to me lol
Its tough to identify over the internet but if you mean it, id appreciate that and i will also try the best from my end to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

To center your lightbox, you'll need to use a lightbox wrapper div that has a width of 100% and is positioned absolutely to take it out of the document flow. Put the lightbox inside so you can center that div within the wrapper.

Also put the HTML **right after** the `<body>` tag to not interfere with the rest of the code.

You can see it in effect here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/6jFyk/1/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: you mean to append it via jquery after closing body tags?

Comment: No, insert it right after the opening body tag as I have done in the fiddle example. If any elements are outside the body tag, there's no telling what might happen :D

Comment: that centers it mate, appreciated but it still does not deal with the scrolling thing.
For the third picture, i need to scroll down to click the thumbnail and the lightbox is up so i need to scrollback up to see it.
Whats the solution to this?

Comment: Use `overflow-y: scroll;` on the lightbox div ( I think this is what you mean?) http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/6jFyk/2/

Comment: You can insert it any way you choose, as long as it's placed right there :)

Comment: I can't connect to the image here. I'll take a better look when I'm at home (on a better computer). Wont be too long :)